# Are these two definitions of Riemann-Stieltjes Integral equivalent

Tags: real-analysis

I actually posted this question before, but didn't get a correct answer. Two distinct definitions follow; ($f$ is assumed to be a real-valued function and $\alpha$ is assumed to be a monotonically increasing function on $[a,b]$)

Definition 1:
$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \text{ a partition } P=\{x_0,...,x_n\} \text{ of } [a,b] \text{ such that } \sum_{i=1}^n [M_i - m_i] \Delta \alpha_i <\epsilon$ where $\Delta \alpha_i=\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})$ and $m_i=\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$ and $M_i=\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$

Definition 2:
$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \text{ a partition } Q=\{x_0,...,x_n\} \text{ of } [a,b] \text{ such that } \sum_{i=1}^n [M_i - m_i] \Delta \alpha_i <\epsilon$ and $d(x_i,x_{i-1})$ is a constant where $\Delta \alpha_i=\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})$ and $m_i=\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$ and $M_i=\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$

Obviously Definition2 implies Definition 1, but what about the converse?

Answer (score 1):

Let $[a,b]=[0,1]$. 
$$\alpha(x) = \begin{cases}
 1 \mbox{ if } x \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\\
 0 \mbox{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 1 \mbox{ if } x \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\\
 0 \mbox{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

For the first definition consider the partition $\{0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\}$, the relevant Darboux sum is 0. So its integrable.

For the second definition, the point $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ will be in the interior of an interval in the parition, as all $x_i$'s will have to rational as they are equally spaced, so the second kind of Darboux sum will be at least 1 irrespective of the equally spaced partition chosen, so the integral does not exist by the second definition.

Comment: The partition $\{0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\}$ is equally spaced. Second definition doesn't mean that all $x_i$'s should be rationals.

Comment: I thought the second definition implied $x_i - x_{i-1} $ is the same. Which means each partition width should be $1/k$ as the length adds upto 1, hence and $x_i = 1/k$.

Comment: I meant i/k above.